Is it possible to use a Deep Network, after learning and validating with different datasets, with only One record (as test)?
I would like to know if it's possible to use a trained deep neural network for evaluation on One record only?
let me explain: I have several datasets. I want to feed them in the deep network, and after training and evaluating on datasets are completed, I want to ask the Network about one record as the test record to get the predicted output. The test record consists of only 2 objects, which have their separate features. The network should have learned the interaction between these features through the deep network.
Is it possible?
I am reading an Article which is similar to what I like to do, but it gets a Dataset for Test process as well. I wonder if I can use the code as my base code to get my desired result.
I am trying to run the code available for the article, but this part isn't explained clearly.
I appreciate any help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
